# Google Spreadsheets with Form Vinculated copy

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to copy a spreadsheet with the responses of a form thought drive API. 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

All files from my drive are working fine but only this spreadsheet that persist my form answers that create a duplicate form instead of only copying the spreadsheet itself.

You can try to reproduce the problem using the given Id. After copying you will notice that both spread sheet and form will be copied. This should not be a problem if I could erase the form but in the response of the copy procedure I don't get any advice about the form that is being copied together.

File id: 0Aqq-9JjR-lUydHRKVEJ2SThGMjJlVjVqczkyWlVCWUE

Please, help me. I'm desperate.

Comment: is this new style, or old style forms. I am not sure if you can unlink old style forms, the form/spreadsheet linking looks to be hard coded in the documents. I think you might need to copy the sheet with google-apps-script or google-spreadsheet-api

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to copy the spreadsheet of the form, try this:

```
var fromSheet = ***whatever***;//this is the sheet attached to your form
var toSheet = ***whatever***;//this will be the sheet that you are copying to
var range =  **whatever***;//this is the range you are copying over. If you are using dynamic ranges (ie varying number of rows), you may want to **getDataRange()** and **getLastRow** to build a more flexible range
function myCopyCat(){
 myValues = fromSheet.getRange(range).getValues();//'copies' all of your data within range from fromSheet to an array
 toSheet.getRange(range).setValues(myValues);//'pastes' all of your data into cells on toSheet
 }
```